# Can we send an XML file directly to an ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic

Right now I have an application that uses a DOM parser to covert the XML file into a message and then send it to ActiveMQ. I was wondering whether can we send the XML file as it is to the queue and then consume and process it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the message isn't too large, you could serialize it into a bytes message and send the whole file to the broker.

You might also consider moving to ActiveMQ Artemis as it supports arbitrarily [large messages](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html).